# The agent process was stopped while the test was running. Test execution from TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, mstest

When i try to execute build dll's using `MSTest/command prompt` from `teamcity` integration all test fails with error.

Even it not open browser instance and fails silently  using `MSTest 10 and MSTest 11(Visual studio 12)`

Error :
"The agent process was stopped while the test was running." (QTAgent)  in result `.trx file` observed.

When i tried to execute same dll from `command prompt (not in team city)` all test executed successfully.

Build is successfully generated using MSBuild.

Thanks,
Shiv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Issue is observed due to TeamCity Build Agent and TeamCity Server run under **System** account but QTAgent and IExplore services run under Administrator user

Solution :

Run TeamCity Build Agent and TeamCity Server using **Administrator** user.

It is better to start Agent using command prompt in agent build folder. (Before start Agent service from command prompt stop already running agent from **services**)

Run Agent using following command :
C:\BuildAgent\bin>agent.bat start

Now Try to run the test it works !!!